# Need some help for creating django field validation in model

Tags: django, python-3.x, validation, django-models

I am trying to validate this BaseProduct model, but I am struck with that so, can someone please pick it up and help me out. Is it possible to validate?
Is there any valid solution?

I need to validate `CharFiled, DecimalField and ImageField`

models.py

```
class BaseProduct(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='', blank="")


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

Comment: No, you don't need to validate `CharField`, `DecimalField` and `ImageField`! If you have to validate something, then it is the fields you defined, be it `name`, `price`, `image`. Let's take a look: `image` is optional, what do you want to validate here? `price` shouldn't have a string as default value, also not an empty string.

Comment: Hi, @cezar thanks to reply, i need validate name, max_length, max_digit, image, choice.

Comment: No, you don't need to validate that. That is why you use a framework. Django takes care about the validation.

Comment: How can i write method save and clean here,

Comment: The documentation covers all that you need to know. You have difficulties with explaining what you really need. For your case those methods shouldn't be needed.

Comment: The documentation covers all that you need to know. You have difficulties with explaining what you really need. For your case those methods shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Thanks cezar for you infromation could helped me.

Comment: @cezar why do you say that charfield doesn't need validation? As CharField could have any character, you need to control the input depending on what the field is for, i.e only alphabetical chars. I'm not trying to argument I'm just curious. (I understand that the field definition gives you a primary validation).

Comment: @guillermochamorro `models.CharField(max_length=200)` will validate that the input is a string with maximum length of 200 characters. It will throw an error if the input isn't a string, or if it is a string longer than 200 characters. I absolutely agree that you can further validate according to your needs, but the OP didn't state anything. What does he need? String with only lower case? String without white space? String without special characters? String made up only of letters and white space?

Comment: @cezar Thanks, I added part of your comment to complete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by validate? You could have all sorts of validations, [some come built in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/) or you could write your own, depending on what type of input you expect

Also in your model definition you have `type = models.CharField(max_length=200`, when your choices are 5 or 6 characters max.

Maybe this is a better approach:

```
PRODUCT_TYPE = (
    ('n', 'Normal'),
    ('c', 'Combo'),
)

type = models.CharField(max_length=1#...`
```

**EDIT**

As @cezar points out, field definition gives you a primary validation, as for CharField:

> models.CharField(max_length=200) will validate that the input is a
>   string with maximum length of 200 characters. It will throw an error
>   if the input isn't a string, or if it is a string longer than 200
>   characters

Comment: Hi,  Guillermo, thanks to reply, i need validate name, max_length, max_digit, image, choice

Comment: Why the downvote? CharFields can have all sorts of custom validatios, because it accepts any character. What if I need to exclude numeric characters for first and last names?

Comment: I didn't give a downvote. i dont have permission to give. so, is there any way to call save and clean method for this model

Comment: @KumarKrishnappa I know you did't, but I can't comment anywhere but my answer. I just want to know what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: Hi @guillermo chamorro, Can you please help how to write get_absolute_url method for this model.

Comment: You can define `get_absolute_url` in the model like this, for detail model:

    `def get_absolute_url(self, **kwargs):
             return reverse('edu:role-detail', kwargs = {'pk': self.pk})`

 The url has to be defined in your `urls.py`. You can use any url in your `urls.py.`